# how to use importrange, sort and transpose at same time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have tow google sheet working codes.
first for transpose data and sort
and second code for import-range

i want to use these at same-time.
i tried but its not working

First working Code

```
=transpose(  sort(
    transpose(A1:L1),
    9 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(A1:L1)), "(?i)wireless"), false,
    7 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(A1:L1)), "(?i)landline"), false,
    5 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(A1:L1)), "(?i)voip"), false,
    3 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(A1:L1)), "(?i)."), false
  )
)
```

Second working Code

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShnTys0k8XIjBbp7pKbMYSCN1BYOkv86GKZfPtZzvsE/edit#gid=518187900", "sheet3!A1:L1")
```

sample sheet here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cMzlVm_9URD6GSdcpaNE1zaFPfmA5eNxqVjksQu4snQ/edit#gid=0

i want to use these at same-time.
importrange from one workbook to another workbook and sort and transpose.
i tried but its not working

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can try with LAMBDA in order to not make it so long. Try with:

```
=LAMBDA(imported,transpose(  sort(
    transpose(imported),
    9 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(imported)), "(?i)wireless"), false,
    7 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(imported)), "(?i)landline"), false,
    5 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(imported)), "(?i)voip"), false,
    3 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(imported)), "(?i)."), false
  )
))(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShnTys0k8XIjBbp7pKbMYSCN1BYOkv86GKZfPtZzvsE/edit#gid=518187900", "sheet3!A1:L1"))
```

Comment: its onle sort and import but doesnot transpose

Comment: Do you need it to be vertical or horizontal?

Comment: i need horizontal

Comment: Could you share something to try?, As long as I have tried it it returns horizontal

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cMzlVm_9URD6GSdcpaNE1zaFPfmA5eNxqVjksQu4snQ/edit#gid=0